# ¿Cómo colocar letra en negrilla en un botón de DevExpress?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Tengo el siguiente botón creado con **DevExpress:**

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(buttonSettings =>
{
    buttonSettings.Name = "btnCancelAppointments";
    buttonSettings.Text = Admin.CancelScheduledAppointments;
    buttonSettings.ControlStyle.VerticalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.VerticalAlign.Bottom;
    buttonSettings.ImagePosition = ImagePosition.Top;
    //buttonSettings.Width = 100;
    //buttonSettings.Height = 50;
    buttonSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "OnClickCancelAppointments";
    buttonSettings.Styles.Style.CssClass = "button-box";
    buttonSettings.Images.Image.Url = "~/Content/Admin/Sync-CamcelrCita.png";
    buttonSettings.Images.Image.Width = 100;
    buttonSettings.Images.Image.Height = 120;
}).GetHtml()
```

El texto lo traigo desde un archivo de recursos como se ve:

```
buttonSettings.Text = Admin.CancelScheduledAppointments;
```

Ese texto es el que debo poner en negrilla, pero no se con qué sintaxis en DevExpress se maneja.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
   @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings => {
        settings.Name = "Button";
        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        settings.ControlStyle.Font.Bold = true; 
     }).GetHtml()
```